# The underlying connection was closed in WCF with Serializers

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service with a service interface

```
[ServiceContract]    
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Person))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Employee))]
    IPerson GetPerson();
 }
```

and my Implementation of GetPerson is

```
 public IPerson GetPerson()
 {
        IPerson obj = new Person();
        obj.FirstName = "Bhuvan";
        obj.LastName = "Ram";        
        return obj;
  }
```

And in my client as simple I used

```
KnownType.MyServiceClient obj = new KnownType.MyServiceClient();
Person objp = (Person)obj.GetPerson()'
```

But when I am trying to access, I am receiving an error

> *The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.*

and my stack trace is like this

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)..

My Employee Class is

> >
>    [DataContract(Name = "Employee")]
>       [KnownType(typeof(IEmployee))]
>       public class Employee:IEmployee
>       {
>           [DataMember]
>           public string EmployeeName
>           {
>               get;set;
>           }
>       }
>
> >
>   My Person Class is 
>      [DataContract(Name = "Person")]
>       [KnownType(typeof(IPerson))]
>       public class Person: IPerson
>    {
>        #region IPerson Members
>        [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
>        public string FirstName { get; set; }

```
 [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 #endregion
```

}

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Post some more code of IPerson to know how the attributes are declared

Comment: If on .NET 4.5 and it worked on .NET 4.0, known issue. Search here or on Google.

Comment: i am using .Net 4.0 and if i use only   [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Person))] its working fine . but if i use multiple known types then as   [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Person))]   [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Employee))] Then its not Working. I would like to access Employee and Person as known types in my class

Comment: Use any one(Knowntype/ServiceKnownType). if you use ServiceKnownType in your ServiceContract, no need to use knowntype in concrete classes. Or else use Knowntype every where.

Comment: Is Employee not IPerson?

Comment: @Jens Kloster:- NO both are different

Comment: @MSK, You are right.. i need to use anyone .. so i used ServiceKnownType. If i am using KnownType i am not able to access the class in my client side. its not generating the MetaData. Now the data is retrieving from Server to Client. Need to check the data whether it is sending from client to server. I will check it and i will update you

Comment: @Bhuvan OK! :) trying to troubleshoot. I think you need to go with MSK 's solution

Comment: You Can.Obviously your client side has the Interfaces(for proxy). How you create proxy (svcutil/ChannelFactory) ? Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160496/problem-with-knowntype-attribute-in-wcf

Comment: um... its working fine .. but only one thing i am able to send the list from client to server , its showing me an error as "Cannot implicitly convert List<Employee> type to object". How do i send this list if i implement List<IEmployee> in person class?

Comment: Check the casting part in client side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220733/how-can-i-pass-a-listinterface-over-wcf.

Comment: Returning Collections using WCF http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/collection-in-wcf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a serialization issue on Concrete class Person.

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IMyService
 {
    [OperationContract]
    IPerson GetPerson();
 } 

 public interface IPerson
 {
   string FirstName { get; set; }
   string LastName { get; set; }
 }

   [DataContract(Name = "Person")]
   [KnownType(typeof(IPerson))]
  public class Person : IPerson
  {
     [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
```

Can use ServiceKnownType attribute on the method signature, rather than using the KnownType attribute on the whole class

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Person))]
IPerson GetPerson();
```

Source:  [Check this link for detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/domgreen/archive/2009/04/13/wcf-using-interfaces-in-method-signatures.aspx)

Ref : [Using Knowntype](http://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly/)

Note:

- Use Knowntype everywhere or ServiceKnowntype on ServiceContract only.
- Try with unique namespace to DataContract of Person and Employee classes.

Comment: Hi if i use only [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Person))] of Person its working fine. But if i use Person and Employee at a time [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Person))] [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Employee))] its not working

Comment: Check out the attributes of Employee like Person. Are they marked properly ?

Comment: Individually both are working fine , but when we combine none of them are working

Comment: Consider two things. 1) Use Knowntype everywhere or ServiceKnowntype on ServiceContract only. 2) Try with unique namespace to DataContract of Person and Employee classes

Comment: you are right , its working fine if i use it. Now i am able to send the data from client to server and server to client also. But if i implement List<IEmployee> getEmpList { get; set; } in my Person class at server side. I am trying to assign the same list at client side to send the data as objPerson.EmployeeList = lstEmp; but the i am getting client side error as "Cannot implicityl convert Employee to object" . How do i overcome this

Comment: Generally, all returned object must be serializable,interfaces cant be serializable. Personally i prefer classes instead of interface as return type.

Comment: Thank you, i am converting to List<object>() as per yor links suggestion