# Serializing a set of derived classes with just its superclass

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have a C# object model that is something like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
abstract class Animal

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
class Cat : Animal

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
class Dog : Animal
```

I have a web service that is like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "animals/{type}")]
    List<Animal> GetAnimals(string type);
```

In my corresponding web service, GetAnimals is defined as such:

```
    public List<Animal> GetAnimals (string type)
    {
        if (type == "cat")
        {
            List<Animal> r = GetCats();
            return r;
        }
        if (type == "dog")
        {
            List<Animal> r = GetDogs();
            return r;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

GetCats is defined as such:

```
    public List<Animal> GetCats()
    {
            List<Animal> toReturn = List<Animal>();
            foreach(Cat c in someDatabase)
            {
                    toReturn.Add(c);
            }
            return toReturn;
    }
```

GetDogs is defined similarly.

When I call the web service via animals/cat or animals/dog , the web service returns nothing. However if I change the OperationContract to return specifically a List or a List, the web service then returns something.

Is there something wrong I'm doing, or is it simply not possible to give an abstract superclass in the OperationContract, and then return its derived classes?

Comment: This code is not sufficient to to know what is wrong.

Comment: Take a look at [Problem with knowntype attribute in wcf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160496/problem-with-knowntype-attribute-in-wcf) or [WCF, Interface return type and KnownTypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108076/wcf-interface-return-type-and-knowntypes)

Comment: Also [Data Contract Known Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).